# Insert Data into Database in Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I got 2 Models, Main Model and Details Model.
In my Home Controller i want to insert 1.000.000 entries into the database, just for testing issues.

But this is very slow, the inserts are happening very slow.. is it possible to speed this up?

Maybe i did something wrong with the configuration?
Because i want, every time a Main entry is saved, a corresponding detail entry should be created.

Main Model looks like:

```
class Main < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :detail, :dependent => :destroy
  before_create :build_a_detail

private
  def build_a_detail
       self.build_detail(:Bezeichnung => 'test', :Koordinaten => 10, :main_id => self.id)
  end
end
```

Detail Model looks like:

```
class Detail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :main
end
```

Home Controller:

```
def new
    for i in 0..1000000
      main = Main.new(:Category => 'Krankenhaus', :Latitude => 5, :Longitude => 6)
      main.save
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that a single insert query is executed into the DB for every create and that slows the application.
You can have bulk inserts with Rails too:
[Bulk insert in RAILS](http://web.archive.org/web/20160310201301/https://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/)

Comment: But if i am doing for example, a single mass insert. Can i still, use the before_create callback in my main model? Or do i have to do this then in the sql query?